# UIView animation for landscape issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewanimation

I have a UIViewController which has a UIView, that I added in a nib file. This is for an iPad project. I wanted to animate so that when the view loads, this UIView appears from the bottom to the center, so I did the following:

```
[self.containerView_ setFrameY:self.view.bounds.size.height];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.containerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

this all works perfectly on portrait, but on landscape it's messed up because the x center of the containerView is not really centered, it's a bit to the left and hence the animation is not transformed over the y axis, but also to the x axis as well..

I think the issue is that if I can get the containerView to be centered regardless of orientation, that would fix it. I have the auto-resizing mask all set correctly so that it's centered. I think the issue is that the view bounds on landscape is still 768x1024 instead of 1024x768. Any idea on this?

Comment: Check your autoresizingMasks, and why not simplify the animation code to: `[self.containerView_ setCenter:self.view.center];` ?

Comment: If you are using center property to move, you can remove autoresizemasks completely since you are comparing with self.view.bounds, which should always set it properly.